# Bootstrap 5 navbar not toggling in Vue3

Tags: navbar, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

This is a similar question to [How can I make navbar items with vue-router-links to toggle the navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70056108/how-can-i-make-navbar-items-with-vue-router-links-to-toggle-the-navbar) but I am not allowed to comment there, and the solution given doesn't work me anyway.

I am using Vue 3 and Bootstrap 5 and the following code works exactly as the standard Bootstrap code does i.e. toggling the hamburger menu opens and closes the menu but clicking a link does nothing (other than correctly route to the page being clicked, meaning user has to then tap hamburger menu again to close)

NavBar component:

```
    <template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <router-link class="navbar-brand" to="/">Birch Farm</router-link> |
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"  
          :class="visible ? null : 'collapsed'" 
          data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
          data-bs-target="#navContent" 
          aria-controls="navContent" 
          :aria-expanded="visible ? 'true' : 'false'"
          @click="visible = !visible" 
          aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <router-link class="nav-link px-3" active-link="active" to="/" @click="visible = !visible">Home</router-link>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <router-link class="nav-link px-3" to="/camping" @click="visible = !visible">Camping &amp; Caravanning</router-link>
              </li>       
              <li class="nav-item">
                <router-link class="nav-link px-3" to="/fishing" @click="visible = !visible">Cat Rough Fishery</router-link>
              </li>  
              <li class="nav-item">
                <router-link class="nav-link px-3" to="/contact" @click="visible = !visible">Contact Us</router-link>
              </li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script setup>
  import {ref} from 'vue'
  const visible = ref(false);
</script>
<script>
export default {
  name: "NavBar",
  created() {},
  data() {},
  props: {},
  methods: {},
  components: {}
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

Not having any of the 'visible' stuff works exactly the same way - this was added when trying the solution given in the above link.

Comment: Have you imported bootstrap's CDN on the index.html or installed bootstrap via npm?

Comment: via npm and the import statements are in main.js e.g.
`import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "toggling the hamburger menu opens and closes the menu but clicking a link does nothing (other than correctly route to the page being clicked"

That's how the Bootstrap Navbar works. It doesn't collapse/hide automatically after clicking a link. Normally you'd have to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401606/how-to-hide-collapsible-bootstrap-navbar-on-click/42401686#42401686) to close the Navbar after clicking a link.

But when using Vue you would toggle the `collapse` class as needed on the `navbar-collapse` div using your `visible` value...

`<div class="navbar-collapse" :class="!visible?'collapse':''" id="navContent">`

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/lHTzN4amfe

Answer (score 1):

I changed `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle` and `data-target` to `data-bs-target` and it worked.

My main.js(main entry file) has this

```
...
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow [this](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs) guide if you are using bootstrap via NPM. As long as I see, the way to use it is different in Angular or React, for example.

In addition to that, if you want to use bootstrap in your project and set it up the easiest way possible, is to use the CDN, I will show you how:

In your main layout, inside the `head` tag, put this:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And inside your `body` tag, this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have a working NavBar using the CDN method?  I have created a new, clean project and defined Bootstrap via the CDN (I prefer that as you can see what you're using and play about) but the NavBar still does not collapse when a link is tapped

Comment: No, sorry. Try taking a look at the documentation, Maybe it will help. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: That all works fine in normal html and React (I've used it many times). It's just Vue that seems to have issues with not collapsing the menu, hence the @click events added above (though they are not working for me)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, bootstrap (5.1.3) and Vue (3.2.36). So I installed bootstrap-vue-3 (0.1.13) and use  and  to make it work.
Also without "navbar-light bg-light) the hamburger icon didn't appear at first.
Hope this helps.

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <RouterLink class="navbar-brand" to="/">
            <img class="logo" src="../assets/svg/logo.svg" />
        </RouterLink>
        <b-button
            v-b-toggle.collapse-1
            variant="primary"
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#menuItems"
            aria-controls="menuItems"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </b-button>
        <b-collapse id="collapse-1" class="mt-2 collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <RouterLink class="nav-link" to=" /">home </RouterLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <RouterLink class="nav-link" to=" /something"
                        >something
                    </RouterLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <RouterLink class="nav-link" to="/about"
                        >about
                    </RouterLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
                <input
                    class="form-control me-2"
                    type="search"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    aria-label="Search"
                />
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
                    Search
                </button>
            </form>
        </b-collapse>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a tweak in this other thread for Vue 3 / Bootstrap 5 / vue-router :
[How to hide collapsible Bootstrap navbar on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401606/how-to-hide-collapsible-bootstrap-navbar-on-click/42401686#42401686)

Adding a simple span tag around menu label and inside li / routerling worked for me:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-sm-0">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <RouterLink class="nav-link" to="/"><span data-bs-target="#navigation" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Menu 1</span></RouterLink>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <RouterLink class="nav-link" to="/ventes.html"><span data-bs-target="#navigation" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Menu 2</span></RouterLink>
               </li>
</ul>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I thought to share my workaround/solution for this specific issue.

Do not use the [router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/api/index.html#routerlink) component, rather trigger the navigation manually via the [push method](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/routerhistory.html#push) in `vue-router` by handling the [click event](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#inline-handlers) in `vue`.

This allows for a "static" layout of the HTML so that you can preserve the functionality in Bootstap which allows for controlling the collapsing of the navbar [via data attributes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/#via-data-attributes).

In order to trigger the active navigation style you can use [class binding](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes) in `vue` and the [route.name](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html#named-routes) value from `vue-router`. It would also work with the path given slight modification.

Here is a basic example:

```
<script setup>
  import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'
  const router = useRouter()
  const route = useRoute()
  const navigate = name => router.push({ name })
</script>
  
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <span class="navbar-brand">EXAMPLE NAVBAR</span>
    <button class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <span :class="['nav-link', route.name === 'camping' ? ' active' : '']"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                @click="navigate('camping')">CAMPING</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <span :class="['nav-link', route.name === 'fishing' ? ' active' : '']"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                @click="navigate('fishing')">FISHING</span>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<li class="nav-item mx-1">  
                        <NuxtLink class="btn nav-button nav-text" to="/eventi">
                            <span data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Servizi</span>
                        </NuxtLink>       
                    </li>
```

I solved adding a span tag with data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" and data-bs-toggle="collapse" around the name of the links (in my case they are NuxtLink but I think works either with Router-link)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding:

```
import * from 'bootstrap';
```

in the app.js file.

After that, it's working.